# IF statement in OpenQASM2.0 on IBM Quantum Experience -- error

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience, qasm

I have written the following toy .qasm file, which has some adaptive measurements:

```
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";
qreg q_1[2];
qreg q_aux[2];
creg c_1[2];
creg c_aux[2];
h q_1[0];
cx q_1[0],q_aux[0];
measure q_aux[0] -> c_aux[0];
if(c_aux[0]==1) s q_1[0];
h q_1[0];
cx q_1[0],q_1[1];
cx q_1[1],q_aux[1];
measure q_aux[1] -> c_aux[1];
if(c_aux[1]==1) s q_1[1];
measure q_1[0] -> c_1[1];
```

The `if` statement is using the formatting that you can find in page 20 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.14722 :

[image]

The problem is that when I try importing this into Qiskit, I get an error:

[image]

So it looks like Qiskit is not liking the notation with the square brackets.

I have done some tests and have noticed that if I replace the if statements by something of the sort of:

```
if(c_aux0==1) s q_1[0];
...
if(c_aux1==1) s q_1[1];
```

then I wouldn't have an error. However, in general, this requires that I replace a single n-bit classical register, by n single-bit classical registers which I don't particularly like.

Does anyone know why the `QasmError` is happening? (Recall that my original code appears to be valid, according to https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.14722 .)

Thank you in advance!

---

sorry everyone this is my first experience with StackExchange and I think I've messed up and made the question as an unregistered user and so I can't seem to be able to change it properly. So I am using this answer to try to add some info (I know this is not how it is supposed to go, I apologize).

@luciano: thank you for your answer, but while the arxiv document is for OpenQASM 3 as you point out, the little snippet of code I took is (in theory) for OpenQASM 2. At least the top of page 20 (right before the code) states:

"*As an example, consider an inverse quantum Fourier transform circuit as written in OpenQASM 2*". So I think that this should work even for OpenQASM 2.0. But when I do:

```
qc1 = QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_file(f'{file_loc}{file_name}.qasm')
```

I get the error that I mentioned. That's what has me confused.

[Edit made by karatechop, copy pasted from answer that was meant to be edit to the question.]

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you are working with OpenQASM version 2 (see your header `OPENQASM 2.0;`). [OpenQASM 2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.03429) can only do conditionals on full classical registers and, as consequence, does not allow bit subindexing in the condition. Your arxiv reference is for [OpenQASM 3](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.14722) which supports conditioning on single qubits.

The IBM Quantum Experience Composer only supports OpenQASM 2. Qiskit allows to do conditionals on single classical bits in coming versions [0.27 or higher](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/pull/6018).

```
qr = QuantumRegister(2, 'qr')
cr = ClassicalRegister(2, 'cr')
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr)
circuit.h(qr[0])
circuit.measure(qr[0], cr[0])
circuit.h(qr[1]).c_if(cr[0], True)
circuit.measure(qr[1], cr[1])
```

However, this circuit cannot be serialized to QASM2

```
circuit.qasm()
```

```
AttributeError: 'Clbit' object has no attribute 'name'
```